# When to consider constraint-equations and when not?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, constrained-dynamics

Below is a first FBD from Robotics And Automation Handbook by T.R. Kurfess. The equations of motion for the system are constructed by using Kane's equations. That is, generalized coordinates $q_1$ and $q_2$ are defined. This leads to a 2 degree of freedom system. Note that $u_i = \dot{q_{i}}$.

[image]

Now, after the problem is adjusted to the situation below. That is, P2 is now only allowed to slide in the n1 direction. A new generalized coordinate is added which is $q_3$ and points in the direction in which $P2$ can slide (note: this coordinate is not shown in the figure). It is said that in this configuration two constraint equations are present:
$$ Ls_1u_1-Ls_{12}*(u_1+u_2) = u_3$$
$$Lc_1u_1 + Lc_{12}(u_1+u_2) = 0$$

where $L$ is the length of the links and $c_i,s_i=cos(q_i),sin(q_i)$. The interpretation is that P2 can not move in $n_2$ direction and only in $n_1$ direction.

What I fail to understand is why these constraint equations come into play when comparing the first and second FBD, and why there is, for example, no constraint equation forcing the point $O$ in the $n$ reference frame. Along the same line, why is there no constraint equation forcing $P1$ to always be at a distance $L$ from $O$ in the first and second FBD?

Additionally, why is the concept of closed kinematic loop not used in this sense? That is, the vector of $O$ to $P_2$ should equal the vector path from $O$ to $P_1$  plus $P_1$ to $P_2$.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

starting with the position vector to $~P_i~$ you obtain

$$\mathbf P_1= \left[ \begin {array}{c} L\cos \left( q_{{1}} \right) 
\\  L\sin \left( q_{{1}} \right) \end {array}
 \right]
\\
\mathbf P_2=\left[ \begin {array}{c} L\cos \left( q_{{1}} \right) +L\cos \left( q
_{{1}}+q_{{2}} \right) \\ L\sin \left( q_{{1}}
 \right) +L\sin \left( q_{{1}}+q_{{2}} \right) \end {array} \right]
$$

if point P can only move towards $~n_1~$ the distance $~h~$ remain  constant

$$h=(\mathbf P_2)_y= L\sin \left( q_{{1}} \right) +L\sin \left( q_{{1}}+q_{{2}} \right) =\rm constant\tag 1$$

this is holonomic constraint equation , from here you can obtain $~q_1=q_1(q_2)~$ so your system has one generalized coordinate.

if you take the time derivation of the constraint equation you obtain
the non-holonomic constraint equation

$$\left( Lu_{{1}}+Lu_{{2}} \right) \cos \left( q_{{1}}+q_{{2}} \right) 
+L\cos \left( q_{{1}} \right) u_{{1}}
=0\tag 2$$

the velocity of point $~P_2~$ towards the $~n_1~$ direction is:

$$ (\mathbf{\dot{P}}_2)_x=u_3(t)\\
 \left( -Lu_{{1}}-Lu_{{2}} \right) \sin \left( q_{{1}}+q_{{2}}
 \right) -L\sin \left( q_{{1}} \right) u_{{1}}=u_3(t)
$$
where $~u_3(t)~$ is given velocity

---

The equation of motion ?

Comment: So, which equation should you use? One with the holomic or non-holomic constraint?

Comment: It doesn’t matter. Do you know how to obtain the EOM’s

Comment: Well, in the context of Kane's equation the governing equation is $F_r + F_r^* = 0$ where $F_r$ represents the generalized active forces and  $F_r^*$ the generalized inertia forces. Moreover, $r=1,..,n$ where $n$ is the number of degrees of freedom. By systematically going through all forces and moments on the bodies and points and applying the correct partial derivatives, one can find the equation of motion.,

Comment: Kane's equation need the generalized velocity coordinates ? ,  form the holonomic constraint equation you obtain $~q_2=q_2(q_1)~$ thus $~q_1~$ is generalized coordinate take the time derivative  for applying Kane's method. or solve the non -holononic equation for $~u_2~$